# What is the reason behind the result of ( ! + [] + [] + ![] )

Tags: javascript

As detailed, this line:

```
(! + [] + [] + ![])
```

Gives as result the string `"truefalse"`

I've been experimenting with it, but cannot fully grasp the implicit conversions happening, would like to know the reason behind the result.

Just curiosity.

Comment: https://dev.to/tpenguinltg/comment/d2mf

Comment: Here is something to confuse those who didn't go deep enough: `Array.prototype.join = () => 1; (! + [] + [] + ![]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
false       =>  ![]
true        =>  !![]
undefined   =>  [][[]]
NaN         =>  +[![]]
0           =>  +[]
1           =>  +!+[]
2           =>  !+[]+!+[]
10          =>  [+!+[]]+[+[]]
Array       =>  []
Number      =>  +[]
String      =>  []+[]
Boolean     =>  ![]
Function    =>  []["filter"]
eval        =>  []["filter"]["constructor"]( CODE )()
window      =>  []["filter"]["constructor"]("return this")()
```

You can find more about it at http://www.jsfuck.com/ .